# PyTest: how to test imported function from another file in project

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

So basically I want to test the top layer of my API, by providing the neccesary interface parameters and utilizing Pytest to do so.

I have a script.py that represents the top layer, it looks something like:

```
def run_local
     'do something here'
return valid_values
```

Then I have my test script in my test.py file. In this file, my input to my decorator is a .yaml file thats set up as additional parameters in my pycharm config. - labeled as config here.

```
import pytest
import os
import sys
from parentdir.script import run_local

@pytest.fixture()
def run_config():
    run_parameters_dir = sys.argv[1]
    return config


def test_run_local_values(config, run_local):
    config = config
    valid_run_local = run_local(config)
    assert all(valid_run_local)
```

The error message i receive is:

*test setup failed
file /test.py

def test_rub_local(config, run_local):
E       **fixture 'run_local' not found***

So i am unable to test my run_local function in my script.py file because I can't seem to import the run_local function correctly in my test.py file. I don't want to mock anything, I actually want to test the function run_local with the parameters that I am importing in my config file. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up some concepts here.

1. It looks like you are using run_local as fixture

> test_run_local_values(config, run_local)

Such fixture does not exist, hence the error.

2. If you want to import the function and use it inside test, you have to call the function inside your test and not pass as argument to test, like this:

   ```
   from parentdir.script import run_local    

   def test_run_local_values(config):
       config = config
       result = run_local(config)
   ```
3. Also fixture "config" doesn;t exist so you cannot pass it to your test.

From your question I think the best solution for you would be to create run_local as fixture that takes on config.

```
from parentdir.script import run_local

@pytest.fixture()
def run_config():
    run_parameters_dir = sys.argv[1]
    return config

@pytest.fixture(run_config)
def run_local
    # 'do something here'
    return valid_values


def test_run_local_values(run_local):
    config = config
    valid_run_local = run_local(config)
    assert all(valid_run_local)
```